# What does scipy.linalg.lu return?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to get the LU composition of a matrix. Since it is suggested that scipy.linalg.lu might not be too accurate, I decided to make sure the maximum absolute error is way less than the minimum element of the matrix I am working with.

Here is a code snippet where I try to LU decompose transpose of A:

```
            print min([min(r[np.nonzero(r)], key=abs) for r in A], key=abs), "min"
            P, L, U = scipy.linalg.lu(np.transpose(A))

            B=np.matmul(np.matmul(P,L),U)
            diff=np.absolute(B-np.transpose(A))

            self.error.append([C, max([max(r) for r in diff])])
            print max([max(r) for r in diff]), "max"
```

The output is as follows:

> 1.8 min
>
> 3.552713678800501e-15 max

which is perfect for me. However, there is a problem.

$$ PA^T=LU $$

$$ A^T= P^{-1}LU $$

Yet, in the third line of the code snippet, I am not multiplying with $P^{-1}$, I multiply it with $P$. For some reason it works perfectly, while it gives me huge errors when I replace P with $P^{-1}$.

Is there something I don't know about np.matmul or scipy.linalg.lu? Does scipy.linalg.lu return P or P^{-1}? Or is there a mistake in my code?

Apologies if this post is not upto stackoverflow standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu.html):

> The decomposition is:
>
> ```
> A = P L U
> ```

It is entirely expected that multiplying the P, L, and U matrices should produce something close to the array originally passed to `scipy.linalg.lu`. You are not supposed to invert P.